# cardview with listview, ugly line between items

Tags: java, android

when i want to insert a cardview in a listview there is ugly line between each item, how to remove it?
[image]

Comment: @tahsinRupam, nope.. take a closer look, he is talking about divider lines

Comment: Please post your layout XML file.

Comment: @donfuxx, right you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set `android:divider=""` or `android:dividerHeight=""` in your listview. I recommend you use [recyclerview](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) instead of listview.

Comment: in your listview item `<ListView ...
    android:divider=""
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />`

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the following XML attribute:

```
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
```

or if you prefer to handle this programmatically, try to call the following method:

```
cardView.setCardElevation(0)
```

Comment: Not really, this affects the drop shadow not the divider line

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/abc"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 android:divider="@null"
 android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```